docker container with aws lambda
I created a very simple nodejs application.
    import express from 'express';

    const app = express();
    const PORT = 3712;

    // Middleware to parse JSON bodies
    app.use(express.json());

    // Logger middleware
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} - ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
      next();
    });

    // Routes
    app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
      console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} - Request received for /test`);
      res.json({ test: 'success' });
    });

    app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
      console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} - Request received for /hello`);
      res.send('hi');
    });

    app.post('/sendkey', (req, res) => {
      console.log(`${new Date().toISOString()} - Request received for /sendkey`);
      const { key } = req.body;
      res.json({ key, accepted: true });
    });

    // Start server
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });

I also build a image for this application
    FROM node:16-alpine

    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    COPY DockerTest/package*.json ./

    RUN npm install 

    COPY DockerTest /usr/src/app/

    EXPOSE 3712

    ENV LOG_LEVEL=info

    CMD ["node", "/usr/src/app/index_test.js"]

Next I pushed container in ECR and built a new lambda function for which i deployed the image. Finally I created an API Gateway for the lambda using REST as a proxy. /{proxy+} resource for ANY method.
Now when i try to execute the endpoint in the browser i see the following log
2024-06-20T14:37:47.952Z    Server is running on port 3712
2024-06-20T14:38:47.821Z    INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 60060.25 ms Phase: invoke Status: timeout
2024-06-20T14:38:47.821Z    START RequestId: a46cbbee-e80a-42ee-8213-87a0a0d33bf8 Version: $LATEST
2024-06-20T14:38:47.825Z    2024-06-20T14:38:47.825Z a46cbbee-e80a-42ee-8213-87a0a0d33bf8 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds
2024-06-20T14:38:47.825Z    END RequestId: a46cbbee-e80a-42ee-8213-87a0a0d33bf8
2024-06-20T14:38:47.825Z    REPORT RequestId: a46cbbee-e80a-42ee-8213-87a0a0d33bf8 Duration: 60064.71 ms Billed Duration: 60000 ms Memory Size: 4096 MB Max Memory Used: 19 MB

My question is what's wrong or even how to diagnose?

I'd take a look at the AWS docs.  You do not try to run a server inside of a server environment.  The port you're listening on isn't magically found by Lambda.

The Error is related to timeout error. Task timed out after 60.06 seconds
So, The Lambda environment are created when it is invoked and each lambda has timeout period maximum is 15 Minutes, and in your lambda currently it is set to 60 Sec(For each request new lambda is invoked). You can increase it to 15 Minutes or as per your requirement by performing following steps:
Note: If your server is taking more than 15 Minutes to process the request then I would suggest to use ECS fargate for processing your request.
Step 1: From Configurations tab you will find General configuration.
Step 2: Edit and update the Timeout period as per your requirement. You can also increase the Memory for Lambda, Which will help to process the request faster.
Check the Lambda Pricing: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

